# Power query append multiple tables with single column regardless column names

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have the following query in M:

```
= Table.Combine({
Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Tab1,{"item"})),
Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Tab2,{"Column1"}))
})
```

Is it possible to get it working without prior changing column names?

I want to get something similar to SQL syntax:

```
select item    from Tab1 union all
select Column1 from Tab2
```

Comment: In Power query, I don't believe it's possible. To get the same result as SQL's `UNION` columns need to be named the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just one column from each table then you may use this code:

```
= Table.FromList(List.Distinct(Tab1[item])
               & List.Distinct(Tab2[Column1]))
```

Comment: you have revealed a workaround to a problem commonly regarded as unsolvable. It is not the first time you helped me. Thank you:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use M (like in your example or the append query option) the columns names must be the same otherwise it wont work.

But it works in DAX with the command

```
=UNION(Table1; Table2)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax

Comment: Thank you. Although I have accepted different answer as relevant to M, I keep using DAX solution as easier to maintain, more readable. I use it in the way suggested in the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57689581/1903793

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Power Query M. Table.Combine make an union with columns that match. If you want to keep all in the same step you can add the change names step instead of tap2 like you did with Table.SelectColumns.
This comparison of matching names is to union in a correct way.

Hope you can manage in the same step if that's what you want.